# How to declare locale specific unit with siunitx?

Tags: babel, siunitx, locale

I am writing a multi-language document in latex.

I am using siunitx package in conjonction with babel to handle every numerical and units related numeric values.

**My goal was to declare a new unit (for instance *\fps*) which would output differently depending on the locale selected.**

I was thus thinking of something like this :

```latex
\documentclass[french,english]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{range-units = single}

\addto\extrasfrench{%
\sisetup{locale = FR, group-separator = {\,}, detect-all}%
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \text{~}]{\fps}{images\text{~}par\text{~}seconde}}

\addto\extrasenglish{\sisetup{locale = US, group-separator = {,}, detect-all}%
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \text{~}]{\fps}{frames\text{~}per\text{~}second}}

\begin{document}

    English: \SIrange{5}{6}{\fps}
    \begin{otherlanguage}{french}

        Français: \SIrange{5}{6}{\fps}

    \end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this idea cannot work since the

```latex
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = \text{~}]{\fps}{frames\text{~}per\text{~}second}
```

macro is then executed within the document and thus resulting in an error ?

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated. What is the deal with those `\text{~} `?

Comment: According to siunitx documentation, it corresponds to a "text-mode full space"

Comment: I don't think declaring a unit for this is the right approach, since you are really setting text and it should behave like text: Line breaks should be allowed, font changes should apply, etc. You should rather define something like `\newcommand*\fpsname{frames per second}\newcommand*\fps[1]{\num{#1}~\fpsname}` and then change `\fpsname` in the usual way when switching languages.

Comment: Close voters: I don't see how this question is unclear. While I don't think it is the right approach for OP's _specific_ situation, it is clearly and well stated and may be relevant for other examples. For example, the (non-SI) unit _horse power_ is regularly denoted differently depending on the language and here a solution like OP is asking for would be appropriate, I think.

Comment: As @schtandard says, really this is not actually a unit at all: it's textual, not 'symbolic' (unit symbols like `m` are symbols not name or abbreviations).

Comment: @schtandard While the question is not completely unclear, IMHO it still lacks some more explanation from the OP regarding the issues raised in the comments. Is the question actually how to define a new local SI unit, and the given textual example is just an unfortunate one? Or is the aim to define different textual units, and the approach to use `siunitx` just wasn't the right one?

Comment: @Flof Could yuo clarify your question as suggested by siracusa?

Comment: @schtandard My aim was to define units with locale specific behavior, the fps example might be corrected from fps in english to ips in french, it could be the same with rpm/tpm (or tr/min). Indeed these units are derived from text but this has nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the facilities of the `translator` package to do this.  If the package is in your system, then `siunitx` loads it automatically.  You can then set up the unit with

```
\DeclareSIUnit{\fps}{ \translate{frames per second} }
```

and declare translations with

```
\newtranslation[to = French]{frames per second}{images par seconde}
```

In your document this gives

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[french,english]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{range-units = single}

\DeclareSIUnit{\fps}{ \translate{frames per second} }

\newtranslation[to = French]{frames per second}{images par seconde}

\addto\extrasfrench{%
\sisetup{locale = FR, group-separator = {\,}, detect-all}}

\addto\extrasenglish{\sisetup{locale = US, group-separator = {,}, detect-all}}

\begin{document}

English: \SIrange{5}{6}{\fps}

\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
  Français: \SIrange{5}{6}{\fps}
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```